# How to iterate through a list of modules and call their methods in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

**Goal:** Ability to drop files into "modules" folder & call a common set of methods/vars from each file.

Should the modules be initialized as static classes if all of the modules have common methods/vars?

**My project folder tree:**

```
/client
    __init__.py

    /modules
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
        spam.py
```

**client __init__.py file:**

```
from client.modules import __all__ as moduleStrings

(get list of "modules" from "moduleStrings") # How do I write this function?

# Initialize modules dynamically
for module in modules:
    if (hasattr(module, 'init')):
        print(module.__name__)
        print("Has an initialize method!")
        module.init()

# Call the do_stuff method in each module
for module in modules:
    if (hasattr(module, 'do_stuff')):
        print("Has a do_stuff method!")
        module.do_stuff()
```

**modules __init__.py file:**

```
# Stores a list of module string names in __all__
import os
import glob
files = glob.glob(os.path.dirname(__file__)+"/*.py")
__all__ = [ os.path.basename(f)[:-3] for f in files if "__init__" not in f]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how your list is "dynamic"?  If you change the number of elements while iterating, then an exception will be thrown.  In other words, you "can't" add or remove elements from the list while iterating.

Comment: You're code seems ok. The approach is fine. What is the question?

Comment: @shx2 I edited to make things more clear. How do I actually iterate through a list of modules and call their common methods/variables?

Comment: @notorious dynamic only in the sense that I can drop files in the modules folder and have it included in the list. The main script will iterate through all modules and call common methods/variables.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on how I could implement this? e.g. - importing modules, initializing modules, and iterating through/calling common methods? The documentation is somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You may use the native python "imp" module (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/imp.html):

**Assuming the same project tree**:

```
/client
__init__.py

/modules
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    bar.py
    spam.py
```

**client **init**.py file:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python

import modules.__init__
#here you generate
modules.__init__.__load_all__()
```

**modules **init**.py file:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python

import imp,os

def __load_all__(dir="modules"):
    list_modules=os.listdir(dir)
    list_modules.remove('__init__.py')
    for module_name in list_modules:
        if module_name.split('.')[-1]=='py':
            print "Load module ' ",module_name,"' :"
            foo = imp.load_source('module', dir+os.sep+module_name)
            foo.MyClass()
```

and finally

**modules (spam.py,bar.py, foo.py, etc...) file:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python

def __init__():
    print "load"

def MyClass():
    print "myclass spam,bar,foo, etc..."
```

When running client `__init__.py`, we iterate through the modules and initialize them dynamically.